# How do I adequately calculate the distribution of function of the multivariate normal distribution using the R mvtnorm package?

Tags: r, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am currently working on an analysis project involving simultaneous testing of several hypotheses. I intend to use the multcomp R package, which calculates the family-wise error rate for multiple hypotheses based on the multivariate normal- / t- distribution, as I understand.

Before I use the multcomp package, I would like to get a better feeling for the multivariate normal- / t- distribution by doing some simulations. Please forgive my informal approach - it is due to a lack of knowledge in higher mathematics, which I would really like to overcome - however, this will take more time :-)

### Univariate normal distriution

For the univariate normal distribution, I can sample random numbers and check empirically that they seem to  follow the intended distribution:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e4
x <- rnorm(n)
p_values <- pnorm(x)
plot(ecdf(p_values))
abline(0, 1, col = 'red', lty = 'dotted')
```

[image]

### Multivariate distribution

I want to do the same thing for the multivariate normal distribution, but so far I am failing:

```
library('mvtnorm')
var_x1 <- 4
var_x2 <- 1
cov_x1_x2 <- 0.3

sigma <- cbind(c(var_x1, cov_x1_x2), c(cov_x1_x2, var_x2))
dat <- rmvnorm(n, mean = c(0, 0), sigma = sigma)

calc_p <- function(x) {
  pmvnorm(lower = -Inf, 
          upper = x, 
          mean = c(0, 0), 
          sigma = sigma)
}


p_values <- apply(dat, 1, calc_p)

# I expect a straight line, but I don't get one:
plot(ecdf(p_values), xlim = c(0, 1))
abline(0, 1, col = 'red', lty = 'dotted')
```

[image: ![](2023-10-10-understanding-the-multivariate-normal-distribution_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png){width=672}]

For more dimensions:

```
n <- 1e3
m <- 10
sigma <- matrix(rnorm(m * m, sd = 0.1), ncol = m)
sigma <- sigma + t(sigma)
diag(sigma) <- 1

dat <- rmvnorm(n, mean = rep(0, m), sigma = sigma)

calc_p <- function(x) {
  pmvnorm(lower = -Inf, 
          upper = x, 
          mean = rep(0, m), 
          sigma = sigma)
}


p_values <- apply(dat, 1, calc_p)

# I expect a straight line, but I don't get one:
plot(ecdf(p_values), xlim = c(0, 1))
abline(0, 1, col = 'red', lty = 'dotted')
```

[image]

I have tried to adhere to the explanations provided in `vignette('MVT_Rnews', package = 'mvtnorm')` and tried to read the documentation carefully but so far I didn't succeed to understand.

Could anyone provide additional explanation and give me a hint, why my R code doesn't produce the desired result?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

### Appendix

Here, I achieved at least some correspondence between the functions:

```
# calculate some quantile:
qmvnorm(p = 0.025,
        sigma = sigma)$quantile
```

```
[1] 0.4784984
```

```
# as to be expected: the value of the quantile doubles if variance is quadrupled
qmvnorm(p = 0.025,
        sigma = sigma * 4)$quantile / 2
```

```
[1] 0.4785318
```

```
# The probability function also yields the desired value: 
pmvnorm(lower = rep(-0.478515, 10), 
        upper = Inf,
        sigma = sigma)
```

```
[1] 0.0250057
attr(,"error")
[1] 1.209307e-06
attr(,"msg")
[1] "Normal Completion"
```